# Preciso fazer uma pesquisa no SQL Server e filtrar apenas de dia e mês (22/12 ate 19/01), como faço para filtrar esses dois dados ignorando o ano?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, data

Possuo esse banco de dados e gostaria de pesquisar apenas por animais nascidos entre 22-12 e 19-01 independente do ano, o que eu preciso fazer para conseguir filtrar essas informações?[img do banco de dados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8O7H.png)

Comment: Pesquisa avulsa ou seria relatório de produção ?

Comment: Pesquisa avulsa mesmo

Comment: Algo assim ... ( (Format(d,'mm/dd') between '12/22' and Format(d,'mm/dd') between '12/31') or (Format(d,'mm/dd') between '01/01' and Format(d,'mm/dd') between '01/19') )

Answer (score -1):

Você pode converter a coluna de data para o formato brasileiro pegando somente o dia e mes

Ficaria algo como : select * from TABELA where convert(char(5),CAMPODATA,103) = '22-12'